# How to find the standard matrix of a shear / reflection transformation R2 to R2

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, linear-transformations, inverse

Let $T : \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ be the transformation that first performs a horizontal shear so that $e_2 \rightarrow e_2 + 2e_1$ (leaving $e_1$ unchanged) and then reflects the points through the line $y = x$

(a) Find the standard matrix $A$ for $T$

(b) Find the standard matrix for the inverse mapping directly by finding a transformation that first undoes the reflection through the line y=x and then undoes the horizontal shear. Show that this matrix is the same as the matrix you found for $A^{-1}$

I'm on (a) and have

$\underbrace{
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x_1 & y_1\\
            x_2 & y_2\\
        \end{bmatrix}
        }_{M}$
$\xrightarrow{(2)e_1 + e_2 \rightarrow e_2}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 & y_1\\
        2x_1+x_2 & 2y_1+y_2\\
    \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1\\
        1 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 & y_1\\
        2x_1+x_2 & 2y_1+y_2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        2x_1+x_2 & 2y_1+y_2\\
        x_1 & y_1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    = T$

(a) $A = T \cdot M^{-1}$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}2x_{1+x_2}&2y_1+y_2\\ \:\:\:\:x_1&y_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{y_2}{x_1y_2-y_1x_2}&-\frac{y_1}{x_1y_2-y_1x_2}\\ \:\:\:\:-\frac{x_2}{x_1y_2-y_1x_2}&\frac{x_1}{x_1y_2-y_1x_2}\end{pmatrix}$
$= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{2x_{1+x_2}y_2-x_2\left(2y_1+y_2\right)}{y_2x_1-y_1x_2}&\frac{-2x_{1+x_2}y_1+x_1\left(2y_1+y_2\right)}{y_2x_1-y_1x_2}\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$

However the result for A seems wonky. Am I on the right track?

Comment: To obtain the standard matrix for a linear transformation, put the images of the basis vectors in the columns

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understanding what you mean. I have the matrix M is that the basis vector in this case? the images being the T? which columns?

I think I'm not setting something up correctly and the A = T * M^-1 is not the correct approach.

Comment: What is $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard matrix for $T$ is $A=RS$, where $S=\pmatrix{1&2\\0&1}$ and $R=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, I was able to find the correct method. I understand your comment now. I was just not contextualizing it correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was not on the right track at all. I needed to set up using an Identity matrix. the solution is as follows.

$T(\vec{x})=A\vec{x}=A_2A_1\vec{x}$

$I=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0\\
   0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$T_1 (e_1)=(e_1)$

$T_1 (e_2)=(e_2)+2(e_1)$

$A_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2\\
   0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$T_2 (e_1)=(e_2)$

$T_2 (e_2)=(e_1)$

$A_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$T(\vec{x})=T_2(T_1(\vec{x}))=A_2A_1\vec{x}$

$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2\\
    0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$